# Javascript code to select/modify data in Word

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, ms-word, office-js

For Word 2013, I am trying to implement a function in Javascript which can delete the entire string between two indices in a MS Word document. The APIs which I have found for Word do not let us do anything (the examples which are available on the MS website involve substituting selected code) of this sort. Is there any available API for doing the same? Thanks in advance. (We are developing in Visual Studio, and are trying to create an Office App)

Comment: what version of office? 2010? 2013? You want to make Addin? App?

Comment: @Taumantis 2013, we're making an app

Comment: so i think it is nice to mention that The name "apps for Office" have changed to "Office Add-ins". And if this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142161.aspx is what you need let me know. But i am sure you can use js in this, becouse I did it.

Answer (score 0):

The extended set of Office JS APIs referred to in a comment applies to Word 2016, only. This extended set enables you to search the entire document.

For Word 2013 your only recourse would be to have the user select the entire document, then get that Word Open XML (the 2013 APIs do let you do that). That returns the OOXML in the OPC flat file format. You can use standard XML editing tools to search and replace in that - making sure the result is valid Word Open XML! - then write that back to the selection.